# DISQUS freezes my computer

Tags: disqus

I've been facing this strange issue from last one month. Whenever I load my blog that is integrated with DISQUS my computer freezes for some seconds and after that the comments get loaded and everything is fine. It happens in both the Firefox and Chrome. My machine is running Windows 7.

Everything was fine before a month ago and suddenly things got changed. I've googled enough and couldn't able to find any solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a temporary solution for this problem by **disabling Disqus 2012 feature in my settings**.